# Yaml / Puppet - Get interface name only with nameservers in the yaml config

Tags: yaml, puppet, netplan

How to get interface name which has `nameservers` defined?

I want to get the interface name so I can pass it to `netplan` puppet module. But I only want to get the interface name (ens160) which has `nameservers` in it.

The Yaml file I want to refer is the netplan config file and its content looks like this:

```
    ethernets:
            ens160:
                dhcp4: no
                addresses: [10.10.10.10/24]
                gateway4: 10.10.10.1
                nameservers:
                    addresses: [20.20.20.20, 30.30.30.30]
                    search: [mydomain.local]
            ens192:
                dhcp4: no
                addresses: [10.10.10.20/24]
```

Comment: Is this data for Hiera with a YAML backend?

Comment: No it is not for hiera.

Comment: I want to pass the interface name to another module

Comment: Hi Mike. I'm afraid this question doesn't have enough context for us to make suggestions. Could you post any code you've tried? And can you explain where that YAML is coming from, if not Hiera? Facts? A separate YAML file?

Comment: The Yaml file is a netplan config file. That's where the IP and DNS servers are set. I want to fetch the interface name which has DNS servers from that and pass it to another puppet module and then replace the DNS servers in that same config file.